# Serve static json file for translations

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-i18n

I'm using `ember-i18n` for translations and I'm trying to fetch translations live as described in [ember-i18n wiki](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Example:-Fetching-Translations-Live)
Instead of loading translations from backend, I would load them from a static file. I've placed files `lang.json` in `/public/i18n/` folder and I retrieve them using a service:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  ajax: inject.service(),  // ember-ajax service
  i18n: inject.service(),

  fetch(lang) {
    if (isEmpty(lang) || !ENV.APP.languages.contains(lang)) {
      lang = "en";
    }
    let url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/i18n/" + lang + ".json";
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.get("ajax").request(url, {
        type: "GET"
      }).then((json) => {
        this.get('i18n').addTranslations(lang, json);
        resolve(lang);
      }, (params) => {
        Ember.Logger.debug(params);
        reject();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

lang.json file contains just the json:

```
{
  "key.foo": "Foo",
  "key.bar": "Bar"
}
```

In dev it works like a charm, but I've some problems running tests. The json retrieved contains the content of the `lang.json` file but it's not loaded into the `i18n` service (for example if I run test with `-s` I see `missing translation xxx` everywhere.

Furthermore, test execution get slower and slower and after 10-15 tests it throws timeout errors.

Am I doing something that shouldn't be done or there something I'm missing?
Thanks

I'm using:
ember-cli: 2.6.2
ember: ~2.6.0
ember-i18n: ~4.2.1

Comment: do you use mirage ? for tests

Comment: Yes, I use mirage v0.1.13 (I will update to v0.2.x soon or later)

Comment: did you add mocks for you lang file into mirage? It should cache response ?

Comment: No, I just set a `this.passthrough('/i18n/**');` because I thought that this way I would read the real file in `/public/i18n/ folder and it does because if I run tests with -s I see that the network response contains file content

Comment: so add mocks for it and tests will run much more faster

Comment: Adding mock tests run faster, thanks for the hint. But now can I return the content of /public/i18n/en.json file? I have a couple of tests where I'm testing the content of the string, not just the key, how can I return the file without copying everything into the mock?

Comment: When you add mock - you can just read file content and use it as mock content ( use import for this )

Comment: It's too common instructions - if you can provide link to your repo , I can check

Comment: I've created a small repo reproducing the problem https://github.com/thagul/load-translation

Comment: Check https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/ (ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC ASSETS) or just add loading file into your tests/index.html and use it inside mirage config

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are suggesting. Can you please share a little example?

Comment: you can try load your translations in tests/index.html and use loaded data in mirage/config ( one option )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for concept ( for your repo )
1) I open `tests/index.html` and modify it next way

```
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
<!-- Next was added -->
<script>
  var translations;
  $.getJSON('/i18n/en.json').then(function(data){ translations = data; });
</script>
```

2) inside `app/mirage/config.js`

```
export default function() {
  this.get("/i18n/:lang", function() {
    return window.translations;
  });
}
```

Git diff for my changes here http://pastebin.com/eGwAXM77

Comment: Many thanks, now I've understood and it works perfectly